# I am curious about a part of the file I/O code in the Linux kernel

Tags: linux, io, linux-kernel

I have a question regarding Linux file I/O.

When writing to a file, the kernel uses the `generic_file_aio_write()` function in which

```c
mutex_lock(inode->mutex);
```

The code runs. (https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.39.4/source/mm/filemap.c#L2545)

What I'm curious about is that just by looking at the name, the `mutex_lock()` function seems to share the lock only within the thread.

But looking through various books, it seems that this `mutex_lock()` process also shares the lock.

Is it correct that this `mutex_lock()` function shares the lock across different processes?

This question arose because in older kernel versions, the `down(&inode->i_sem)` function was executed when performing locking.
(https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.6/source/mm/filemap.c#L1977)

From related books and simple experiments
`mutex_lock(inode->mutex)` in `generic_file_aio_write()` I confirmed that locks are shared between different processes, but
It's not clear, so I'd like to find a more definitive way.

Comment: The whole point of a mutex is to lock something between different threads.

Comment: Kernel part of address space is shared between all processes. There is no processes/threads separation.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @dimich Thank you for answer.  Could you please tell me a document or method by which I can check it?